# MySQL getting each first unique row from sorted by a date column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table as below, I'm having trouble getting the results  I want.

What I want is to get just the recent message of every unique `user_id`. I have asked a similar question before, but I feel like an idiot because I still does not get it. How am I suppose to use MySQL `order by` and `group by` together? Using `distinct` doesn't work either.

```
+---------+---------------------+------------------+
| user_id | created_at          | message          |
+---------+---------------------+------------------+
|       2 | 2011-02-06 19:53:59 | sd               |
|       2 | 2011-02-06 20:11:41 | working on st..  |
|       3 | 2011-02-06 20:40:14 | testing applica..|
|       3 | 2011-02-06 21:35:11 | testing appli..  |
|       3 | 2011-02-06 23:09:34 | testing af..     |
+---------+---------------------+------------------+
```

**This is how it should return**

```
+---------+---------------------+------------------+
| user_id | created_at          | message          |
+---------+---------------------+------------------+
|       2 | 2011-02-06 20:11:41 | working on st..  |
|       3 | 2011-02-06 23:09:34 | testing af..     |
+---------+---------------------+------------------+
```

This does return in right format, but it fetches some random message.

```
select user_id,created_at, message from status group by user_id order by created_at desc
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  created_at,
  message
FROM
  status
    JOIN
      (SELECT user_id,MAX(created_at) AS max 
       FROM status 
       GROUP BY user_id) max_created_at ON 
     (max_created_at.user_id = user_id AND max_created_at.max = created_at)
```

Comment: i did actually try to use sub queries, but gets mixed up half way. thought there would be an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct(user_id) from status order by created_at  DESC
```

Comment: `message` is important, don't think distinct works with multiple fields.

Comment: select distinct(user_id), message from status order by created_at  DESC

That can't return everything.

Comment: i ran into that issue, that is why i posted the question. i ran your query again, it returns four out of five records instead of expected two. sorry i said everything.

Comment: distinct is select modifier, not column modifier. distinct (user_id) , message == distinct (user_id,message )